# Matrix Chain Multiplication

Tags: c, recursion, matrix-multiplication

On the website [geeksforgeeks](http://geeksforgeeks.org) I came across the task of [**matrix chain multiplication**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/).

There is a recursive solution for that problem, but I am having trouble understanding the code. Actually, I am having trouble with a certain line of the code.

First of all here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

//Matrix Ai has dimension p[i-1] x p[i] for i = 1...n
int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int i, int j)
{
    if(i == j)
        return 0;
    int k, min = INT_MAX, count;

    for(k=i; k < j; k++) {
        count = MatrixChainOrder(p,i,k) + MatrixChainOrder(p,k+1,j) + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];

    if(count < min)
        min = count;
    }

    return min;
}

int main() {

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("Minimum number of multiplications is %d ", MatrixChainOrder(arr, 1, n-1));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The matrices are: A=1x2, B=2x3, C=3x4, D=4x3

The line, which is causing me some trouble is

```
count = MatrixChainOrder(p,i,k) + MatrixChainOrder(p,k+1,j) + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
```

At the beginning of the for-loop, `i = 1` and `j = 4`. So, **`p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]`** would evaluate to **`p[0]*p[1]*p[4] = 1x2x3`**, which is obviously wrong, because the matrix A can only multiplied with B. I ran the code and nothing seem to be happening here, because there was no result given back for **`p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]`** and also the same issue for the case `i = 2, j = 4`.

May anyone enlighten me? I would appreciate it, if you explain me the recursion in this code. I mean the way and how it works.

Comment: I don't see any C++ in the code snippet, so I took the liberty of changing the language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in what the recursion is doing.  Assuming that this represents multiplying `ABCD`, then the iteration of the loop with `i=1, j=4, k=1` represents performing this calculation by `(A)(BCD)`.  `MatrixChainOrder(p,i,k)` computes the best way to calculate `(A)`, a `1x2` matrix, and `MatrixChainOrder(p,k+1,j)` computes the best way to calculate `(BCD)`, a `2x3` matrix.

Finally, the term you are interested in `p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]` is the number of scalar multiplications to perform the final multiplication of `(A)` and `(BCD)`.